# Python DataFrames concat or append problem

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataset

I have a problem with dataframes in Python. I am trying to copy certain rows to a new dataframe but I can't figure it out.

There are 2 arrays:

```
pokemon_data

    #   HP  Attack  Defense Sp. Atk Sp. Def Speed
0   1   45  49  49  65  65  45
1   2   60  62  63  80  80  60
2   3   80  82  83  100 100 80
3   4   80  100 123 122 120 80
4   5   39  52  43  60  50  65
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
795 796 50  100 150 100 150 50
796 797 50  160 110 160 110 110
797 798 80  110 60  150 130 70
798 799 80  160 60  170 130 80
799 800 80  110 120 130 90  70

800 rows × 7 columns
```

```
combats_data


    First_pokemon   Second_pokemon  Winner
0   266 298 1
1   702 701 1
2   191 668 1
3   237 683 1
4   151 231 0
... ... ... ...
49995   707 126 0
49996   589 664 0
49997   303 368 1
49998   109 89  0
49999   9   73  0

50000 rows × 3 columns
```

I created third dataset with columns:

```
output1

    HP0 Attack0 Defens0 Sp. Atk0    Sp. Def0    Speed0  HP1 Attack1 Defense1    Sp. Atk1    Sp. Def1    Speed1  Winner
```

What I'm trying to do is copy attributes from **pokemon_data** to **output1** in order from **combats_data**.

HP0 and HP1 are respectivly HP from first Pokemon and HP from second Pokemon.

I want to use that data in neural networks with TensorFlow to predict what Pokemon would win.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @karolkens!  Can you provide your dataframes in a form that can be easily copied (i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame([ ... ])`)?  Also, can you show us a few rows of the output you expect?  It's not immediately clear what you want the merging to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution from user part from 4programmers.net forum.
    import pandas as pd

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pokemon_data = pd.DataFrame({
        "Id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "HP": [45, 60, 80, 80, 39],
        "Attack": [49, 62, 82, 100, 52],
        "Defense": [49, 63, 83, 123, 43],
        "Sp. Atk": [65, 80, 100, 122, 60],
        "Sp. Def": [65, 80, 100, 120, 50],
        "Speed": [45, 60, 80, 80, 65]})
    combats_data = pd.DataFrame({
        "First_pokemon": [1, 2, 3], 
        "Second_pokemon": [2, 3, 4], 
        "Winner": [1, 0, 1]})

    output = pokemon_data.merge(combats_data, left_on="Id", right_on="First_pokemon")
    output = output.merge(pokemon_data, left_on="Second_pokemon", right_on="Id",
                          suffixes=("_pokemon1", "_pokemon2"))

    print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this type of wrangling, you should first "melt" or "tidy" the `combats_data` so each ID has its own row, then do a "join" or "merge" of the two dataframes.

You didn't provide a minimum reproducible example, so here's mine:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5],
                    'var1': [10,20,30,40,50],
                    'var2': [15,25,35,45,55]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id1': [1,2],
                    'id2': [3,4],
                    'outcome': [1,4]})

df2tidy = pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['outcome'], value_vars=['id1', 'id2'],
                  var_name='name', value_name='id')

df2tidy
#   outcome name    id
# 0 1       id1     1
# 1 4       id1     2
# 2 1       id2     3
# 3 4       id2     4


output = pd.merge(df2tidy, df1, on='id')

output
#   outcome name    id  var1    var2
# 0 1       id1     1   10      15
# 1 4       id1     2   20      25
# 2 1       id2     3   30      35
# 3 4       id2     4   40      45
```

which you could then train some sort of classifier on `outcome`.

(Btw, you should make `outcome` a 0 or 1 (for pokemon1 vs pokemon2) instead of the actual ID of the winner.)

Answer (score 0):

So i would like to create new array based on these two arrays. For example:

```
#ids represent pokemons and their attributes
pokemons = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5],
                    'HP': [10,20,30,40,50],
                    'Attack': [15,25,35,45,55],
                    'Defese' : [25,15,45,15,35]})

#here 0 or 1 represents whether first or second pokemon won
combats = pd.DataFrame({'id1': [1,2],
                    'id2': [3,4],
                    'winner': [0,1]})

#in output data i want to replace ids with attributes, the order is based on combats array
output = pd.DataFrame({'HP1': [10,20],
                    'Attack1': [15,25],
                    'Defense1': [25,15],
                      'HP2': [30,40],
                    'Attack2': [35,45],
                    'Defense2': [45,15],
                    'winner': [0,1]})
```

Not sure if its correct thinking. I want to train neural network to figure out what pokemon will win.